# How to locate this <a> element with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is a button “Apply Now” on http://yearup.org.

```
<a href="https://www.yearup.org/seize-opportunity/" class="button">Apply Now</a>
```

So far I tried:

```java
//*[@class='button']") (but there are 11 occurrences. Using [0] doesn't help
```

```java
//*[@class='button']//*[text()='Apply Now']
```

```java
"html/body/div/section[2]/header/section/ul/li/ul/div[2]/a"
```

```java
.findElement(By.linkText("Apply Now"));
```

None of them worked for me.

Following error is obtained:

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element
> ```

Comment: That's not saying that it couldn't be located. It's saying it's in the wrong state. Perhaps it's in a dropdown menu or similar that hides it until something else happens.

Comment: Thank you. The question looks more concise now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes it a bit hard, is a duplicate of same tag in same page. 
There are two solutions:

```
//div[@class='large-9 columns large-centered center-absolute']/a[@class='button' and contains(text(),'Apply Now')]
```

or

```
(//a[contains(text(),'Apply Now')])[2]
```

Comment: I will check this time once I am home

Comment: I was able to click using both options provided using Chrome, will test it tomorrow using IE.  Got some issues in console when launched with Chrome though. But..it works :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@href='http://www.yearup.org/seize-opportunity/']")).click();
```

If you are only trying to locate it and not click the element, then use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@href='http://www.yearup.org/seize-opportunity/']"));
```

And further, if you are trying to travel to that page and you don't need to actually click on the element to travel there, just do:

```
driver.get("http://www.yearup.org/seize-opportunity/");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I feel like there should be a better option then this. It has to work even if the url of the link “Apply Now” changes. Simply selecting it by the url address doesn’t seem to be the best option. I appreciate your efforts though!

Comment: If you're testing the button, you have to click it. If you're just going to the page (because you're testing something on that page), you don't. In fact, in that case, you _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 2):

I know in the HTML it shows up as "Apply Now" but if you use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("APPLY NOW")).click();
```

it works. I just tested it.

Comment: Yeah... I see this from time to time. If it's all caps on the page but sentence caps in the HTML, all caps will work in `.linkText()`.

Comment: It's not only about upper/lower case. In case of search by `linkText` text that appears on rendered page should always be used instead of the value from HTML source. @Gregory Povorozniuk , [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your issue